# Is this context free or regular

Tags: context-free-grammar

Strings over the alphabet `{a, b, c, d}` where no `c` is immediately followed by an `a` and no `d` is immediately followed by `b`.

This would be a context free and not regular right?

Comment: I think this is context-free and not regular.

Comment: Hint: this is as regular as languages get.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a question like this, you are generally going to want to assume the most restrictive kind of language, then attempt to disprove it. If you can't disprove it, you need to find a way to express it using an appropriate grammar or automaton. If you can disprove it, move to the next level of the hierarchy and repeat.

In this case, you have at least two options to try to prove that the language isn't regular: the pumping lemma for regular languages, and the Myhill-Nerode theorem. If the language cannot be proven irregular from these, you'll need to right a regular grammar, regular expression, or finite automaton for exactly that language. Often, failed attempts at using the pumping lemma or Myhill-Nerode theorem give some insight as to how the you might find such representations of regular languages (for instance, the pumping lemma can show you that there must be a potential for a cycle in a finite automaton, and the Myhill-Nerode theorem can show you how many states a finite automaton must have, and what transitions must go between them).

> This would be a context free and not regular right?

Why would you say that? Post the argument leading to this conclusion, and I will evaluate the argument.